# CakePHP more than one belongsTo

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I have more than one belongsTo for a model?

e.g.

```
<?php

class Appointment extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Appointment';

    var $useTable = 'appointments';

    var $belongsTo = 'Client','Doctor';
}

?>
```

Which breaks the app...

As appointments belong to both a Client and a Doctor and clients can have many appointments and doctors many appointments (these associations work fine, it's just the belongsTo that isn't working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var $belongsTo = array('Client','Doctor');
```

it's called array. more about arrays in **<sup>[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)</sup>**

Comment: I have but had to wait as it has a timer before you can accept it!